# Sequence not working as expected

Tags: sequence

From the help page:

```
f[a, Sequence[b, c], d]
```

No problem at all.

```
ans = {2, 3, 23, 2, 3412, 421};
ans = Drop[ans, {1, 2}];
f[{a, b}, c, {d, f, g}, Sequence[ans]]
```

Not working?

```
f[{a, b}, c, {d, f, g}, Sequence[ans[[3 ;;]]]]
```

Does not work either.I expect something like this

```
f[{a, b}, c, {d, f, g},23, 2, 3412, 421]
```

How would I use `Sequence` in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ans` is a list so you need to apply sequence.

```
ans = {2, 3, 23, 2, 3412, 421};
ans = Drop[ans, {1, 2}]
f[{a, b}, c, {d, f, g}, Sequence @@ ans]
```

> ```
> f[{a, b}, c, {d, f, g}, 23, 2, 3412, 421]
> ```